# $X\to\infty$ and $Y\to\infty$ independently

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, integration, improper-integrals

I was reading this definition

**Definition** Suppose $\int_{-X}^{Y} f(t) \, dt $ exists for all $Y>-X$. If $\int_{-X}^{Y} f(t) \, dt $ tends to a finite limit as $X\to\infty$ and $Y\to\infty$ independently, then that  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \, dt $ exists.

My question is

what does it mean that  $X\to\infty$ and $Y\to\infty$ independently? Also $X\to\infty$ and $Y\to\infty$ dependently?

Comment: it probably means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M > 0$ such that for $X, Y \geq M$, ... I think it is the same kind of limit as in the definition of a Cauchy sequence

Comment: It means that for every pair of sequences $x_n\leq y_n$, $n=0,1,2,...$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=+\infty$, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-x_n}^{y_n}f(t)dt$ exists. This, as opposed to not considered all sequences, maybe even just one sequence, like $\int_{-n}^{n}f(t)dt$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assumming that $X,Y>0$. Here, $X\to \infty, Y\to\infty$ 'independently' means that $X,Y$ cannot have any relationships with one another. For example, $Y=X^2$ or $Y=X$ means that they are not independent (and thus are dependent). It is important that the integral converges to a unique limit as $X,Y\to\infty$ **independently** because we want to rule out certain cases where the integral will converge to a finite limit when $X,Y$ are in a certain relationship. For example, if $Y=X$ then
$$\int_{-X}^Y \sin(t) \, dt =0$$
and thus, as $X,Y\to\infty$ (dependently in this case), it looks as though
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(t) \, dt =0$$

For the rigorous definition, the integral $$\int_{-X}^Y f(t) \,dt$$ tends to a finite limit as $X\to \infty, Y\to \infty$ independently means that there is a number $L$ such that for any $\epsilon >0$, there will be a $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $X,Y>M$ then $$\left| \int_{-X}^Y f(t) \, dt - L \right|<\epsilon$$
Notice that the definition only requires $X,Y$ to be larger than $M$, not by how much. Thus, $X$ can be much larger, smaller or just equal to $Y$ and so they are independent in this sense.

Comment: David Dinh , thank you for your answer. To make the idea clear let consider the following $\int _{-X}^{Y} \frac{t}{1+t^2} dt $ where $X, Y$ go to $\infty$. If $X, Y, $ are dependent. How can we consider the relation between $X,Y$ to find the integral?

Comment: By finding the integral, I think you mean finding the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{t}{1+t^2} \, dt$$ The thing is you cannot evaluate this integral because it is not defined. On the other hand, if you want to form relationships between $X,Y$ so that you do get some limits then we can take advantage of the fact that the integrand is an odd function. Thus, as long as $X=Y$ or $X^2 = Y^2$ then in the limit, you will always get zero.

Comment: David Dinh. How the odd function would help here ? Also, why you just considered the cases $ X=Y$ or $Y^2=X^2$

Comment: Odd functions possess the property that their integrals on a symmetric domain $[-n,n], n>0$ is always zero. That's why it is relevant. 

I gave $X=Y$ and $X^2=Y^2$ as examples. The point is that you want a symmetric (around zero) domain of integration. You could have considered $e^X=e^Y$ as well.

Comment: David Dinh. Wstill not clear the way that you found the relation between $x$ and $ Y$. Since for example. Consider $X= Y^3$?

Comment: If $X=Y^3$ then your integral is on in the interval $[-Y^3, Y]$ which may not be symmetric. For example if $Y=2$ then the interval is $[-8, 2]$. On the other hand, if we picked $X^2 = Y^2$ then the interval $[-X^2, Y^2]=[-Y^2,Y^2] $ is symmetric.

Comment: David Dinh. Okay. Does this mean we have to consider cases cases to solve this kind of problem? Since in case independently it’s easy to check that the integral does not exists

Comment: Yes and the possibilities are endless.

Comment: David Dinh. It is kind of strange since I saw this question in an exam