# Improper integral with dependent boundaries

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

This question is related to [$X\to\infty$ and $Y\to\infty$ independently](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4518934/707884).

Consider the following problem $\int_{-X}^{Y}  \, \frac{2t}{t^2+1}$
where
(i) where $X,Y\to \infty$ independently.    (ii) where $X,Y\to \infty$ dependently

For (i), $\int_{-X}^{Y}  \, \frac{2t}{t^2+1}dt=\ln |Y^2+1|-\ln |X^2+1|$ , since $X,Y\to \infty$ independently. So, $\int_{-X}^{Y}  \, \frac{2t}{t^2+1}dt$ is divergent as $X,Y\to \infty$ independently.

For (ii), I do not know what I suppose to do. If $X=Y$ or $X^2=Y^2$, or some similar cases, the  $\int_{-X}^{Y}  \, \frac{2t}{t^2+1}dt$ would be convergent. But for other cases, for example, $X=Y^4$ would not be.

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln [Y^{2}+1]-\ln [X^{2}+1]=\ln \frac {Y^{2}+1} {X^{2}+1}=\frac {1+Y^{-2}} {(X/Y)^{2}+Y^{-2}}$. Note that $Y^{-2} \to 0$. So $\ln [Y^{2}+1]-\ln [X^{2}+1]$ has  finite limit if and only if $\frac {1+Y^{-2}} {(X/Y)^{2}+Y^{-2}}$ has  a finite positive limit if and only if $(X/Y)^{2}$ has  a non-zero limit. Equivalently, $\frac X Y$ has  non-zero limit.

Comment: geetha290krm. I agreed . But it means in case independent the integral does not exist. But the in case dependent the $\frac{X}{Y}$ might zero as $X,Y$ go to infinity .for example , $Y=X^2$. Is that right? So case ii is divergent . Right ?

Comment: Yes, if $Y=X^{2}$ it is divergent.  @Gob

Comment: @geetha290krm, I got confused. in the case independently, what is the limit? because we can not consider any relationship between $x$ and $y$. right?

Comment: When $X$ and $Y$ vary independently  the limit does not exist. @00GB

Comment: @geetha290krm, thank you for getting back to me. But how?

Comment: If the limit exists when $X$ and $Y$ vary independently then it exists even if they depend in any particular way and we know this is not true. @00GB

Comment: @geetha290krm, could you please clarify that "then it exists even if they depend in any particular" how can we show that?

Comment: @00GB Just write down the definition. If the limit of $F(X,Y)$ exits and equals $l$ then there exists $M$ such that $|F(X,Y)-l|<\epsilon$  **whenever** $X>M$ and $Y>M$. The emphasis here is on the word **whenever**.

Comment: @geetha290krm. I see your point. Thank you so much